# search function is too slow recordclass python optimization

Tags: python-3.x, performance, optimization, compiler-optimization, cpython

`Dict()` are memory consuming so I tried to use other way. using dataobject what took in 6Gb it's now 700M. However, when it comes to search, it very slow what i implemented

I know I can't compete with python, but at least make it better

Please if you have any idea maybe Cpython

First: I tried chained nodes but still slow

```
from recordclass import dataobject
class node(dataobject):
      elt1:tuple
      elt2:list
      _next:str


def find(n1,elt1): 
  if n1 is None: 
    return None 
  if n1.elt1==elt1: 
    #print(n1.elt2)
    return n1.elt2
  else: 
    return find(n1._next,elt1) 
#or

def find1(n1,elt1):
  while n1 is not None:
    if n1.elt1==elt1: 
      #print(n1.elt2)
      return n1.elt2
    else:
      n1=n1._next

n1=None 
daca=dict()
for i in range(0,100,2): 
  n1=node(i,i+1,n1) 
  daca[i]=i+1


#find(n1,12) compared to daca[12], dictionary is 7 times faster than find
```

second: I tried to append all the nodes to a list but yet still slow

```
from recordclass import dataobject
class node(dataobject):
      elt1:tuple
      elt2:list


def find(n1,elt):
  return list(filter(lambda x: x.elt1==elt ,n1))


n1=[] 
daca=dict()
for i in range(0,100,2): 
  n1.append(node(i,i+1) )
  daca[i]=i+1

#find(n1,12) compared to daca[12], dictionary is 7 times faster than find
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to bite python dict for seaching values by key.

Recordclass library could help to reduce memory footprint in the following way.

```
from recordclass import make_arrayclass, litelist
from random import randint
```

The `tracemalloc` module is used to evaluate memory footprint:

```
import tracemalloc
class Tracer:
    def __enter__(self):
        if tracemalloc.is_tracing():
            raise ValueError('nesting tracemalloc is not allowed')
        self.allocated = None
        tracemalloc.start()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
        tracemalloc.stop()
        self.allocated = current
```

First  to estimate the "weight" of dict's part:

```
with Tracer() as t0:
   d0 = {i:None for i in range(5_000_000)}
print("dict:", t0.allocated // 1_000_000, 'Mb')
del d0, t0
```

The result is 307 Mb

Second let's estimate the memory footprint of the dictionary with 5_000_000 entries. The key is a triple of random integers, the value is a list with 6 random integers.

```
with Tracer() as t1:
    d1 = {}
    for i in range(N):
        key = (randint(0,N), randint(0,N), randint(0,N))
        val = [randint(0,N) for i in range(10)]
        d1[key] = val
print("regular:", t1.allocated // 1_000_000, 'Mb')
del d1, t1
```

The result is 3387 Mb. So the dict's part is relatively small.

In order to reduce the memory footprint of tuples and lists it can be used `make_arrayclass` and `litelist` from `recordclass` library:

```
Triple = make_arrayclass("Triple", 3, hashable=True)

with Tracer() as t2:
    d2 = {}
    for i in range(N):
        key = Triple(randint(0,N), randint(0,N), randint(0,N))
        val = litelist([randint(0,N) for i in range(6)])
        d2[key] = val
print("recordclass:", t2.allocated // 1_000_000, 'Mb')
del d2, t2
```

The result is 2107 Mb. So this save about 1 Gb.

P.S.: Python 3.7 is used.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, what I'm doing now is using hdf5 as you can go directly to the path you want. if you r interested in this just lemme know, i will upload the code to github.